# Finding $x$ where inequality is satisfied for sure

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, special-functions

I have following inequality 
$$ \frac{e^x}{x} \geq M$$
where $x$ is positive and the constant number $M$ is also positive. $e$ is Euler's number.

Does someone know some reference or have knowledge about finding $x$, where the inequality is fulfilled?

I tried to use Lambert W function, but it only leads to complex numbers, which is not helpful for my problem, since I need $x$ to be real and positive.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- The minimum value of $\frac{e^x}{x}$ is $e$. For $M \le e$, all $x \ge 0$ satisfy the inequality.
- When $M > e$, then $e^x=Mx$ has two real solutions as found by Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: In my case $M$ is greater $e$. Can you explain a bit more how you would use Lambert W function, since for Lambert I need the form $xe^x=M$, but you wrote $e^x = Mx$. And when I use substitutions to get the form $xe^x=M$, my Lambert W is getting complex, which is bad for me.

Comment: How about letting $y=-x$ to get $e^{-y}=-My \implies y e^y = -1/M \implies -x = y = W(-1/M)$.

Comment: Yeah, that's a way. I observe that I need the solutions given by the Lambert $W_{-1}$ branch. Do you know some bounds for the solution given by the $W_{-1}$ branch? Since I have a inequality and not an equality and I would be very happy if there are some bounds. ;-)

Comment: @N.Younger The function $\frac{e^x}{x}$ is an increasing function for $x \ge 1$ and a decreasing function for $0 < x < 1$. One of the solutions of $e^x=Mx$, say $x_1$, must be $x_1 \ge 1$, whereas the other one, $x_2$ must be less than 1. The inequality will be satisfied if $x \ge x_1$ or $0 < x \le x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $M\leq1$ then $e^x\geq1+x$ shows that the inequality holds for all $x$. If $M>1$ you can use $e^x\geq1+x+x^2/2$ to find the sufficient condition
$$1-(M-1)x+x^2/2\geq0.$$
This holds for all $x$ if $(M-1)^2-2<0$ and it holds for all
$$x>M-1+\sqrt{(M-1)^2-2}$$
otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case $M>1$ is always true. Could you give me some reference for that case or could you give me an explanation? Since I need to know why we can use your hints you wrote here. Thanks!

Comment: In case $M>1$: The inequality $e^x \geq 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$ is really conservative. It leads to values which surely satisfy the origin inequality, but there are too large.

Comment: It is just the Taylor expansion. $e^x\geq\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n/n!$. For $N=1$ you get $e^x\geq1+x$ which proves your inequality for $M\leq1$. If $N=2$ you get the sufficient condition that I stated in my answer. For $N>2$ you get tighter sufficient conditions, but they are harder to evaluate.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I see. I think this way is not good for my case.